# Select field only if it exists (SQL or Scala)

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

The input dataframe may not always have all the columns. In SQL or SCALA, I want to create a select statement where even if the dataframe does not have column, it won't error out and it will only output the columns that do exist.

For example, this statement will work.

```
Select store, prod, distance from table

+-----+------+--------+
|store|prod  |distance|
+-----+------+--------+
|51   |42    |2     |
|51   |42    |5     |
|89   |44    |9     |
```

If the dataframe looks like below, I want the same statement to work, to just ignore what's not there, and just output the existing columns (in this case 'store' and 'prod')

```
+-----+------+
|store|prod  |
+-----+------+
|51   |42    |
|51   |42    |
|89   |44    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have list of all cols in list, either hard coded or prepare from other meta data and use intersect

```
val columnNames = Seq("c1","c2","c3","c4")

df.select( df.columns.intersect(columnNames).map(x=>col(x)): _* ).show()
```

Comment: I do get this error while trying it in my real dataset: <console>:153: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `columns` method on `Dataframe`. This would look like that:

```
val result = if(df.columns.contains("distance")) df.select("store", "prod", "distance") 
             else df.select("store", "prod")
```

Edit:

Having many such columns, you can keep them in array, for example `cols` and `filter` it:

```
val selectedCols = cols.filter(col -> df.columns.contains("distance")).map(col)
val result = df.select(selectedCols:_*)
```

Comment: I am trying to do this on a dataframe with about 100 columns. I don't always know what column the dataframe will have missing. Is there a more dynamic way of doing it? Something like a select All, that just ignores the columns that do not exist.

Comment: No problem. If it helped, consider upvoting / marking as correct;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the expanded SQL template, like `select a,b,c from tab`, you could do something like below to get the required results.

1. Get the sql string and convert it to lowercase.
2. Split the sql on space or comma to get the individual words in an array
3. Remove "select" and "from" from the above array as they are SQL keywords.
4. Now your last index is the table name
5. First to last index but one contains the list of select columns.
6. To get the required columns, just filter it against df2.columns. The columns that are there in SQL but not in table will be filtered out
7. Now construct the sql using the individual pieces.
8. Run it using spark.sql(reqd_sel_string) to get the results.

Check this out

```
scala> val df2 = Seq((51,42),(51,42),(89,44)).toDF("store","prod")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [store: int, prod: int]

scala> df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tab2")

scala> val sel_query="Select store, prod, distance from tab2".toLowerCase
sel_query: String = select store, prod, distance from tab2

scala> val tabl_parse = sel_query.split("[ ,]+").filter(_!="select").filter(_!="from")
tabl_parse: Array[String] = Array(store, prod, distance, tab2)

scala> val tab_name=tabl_parse(tabl_parse.size-1)
tab_name: String = tab2

scala> val tab_cols = (0 until tabl_parse.size-1).map(tabl_parse(_))
tab_cols: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(store, prod, distance)

scala> val reqd_cols = tab_cols.filter( x=>df2.columns.contains(x))
reqd_cols: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(store, prod)

scala> val reqd_sel_string = "select " + reqd_cols.mkString(",") + " from " + tab_name
reqd_sel_string: String = select store,prod from tab2

scala> spark.sql(reqd_sel_string).show(false)
+-----+----+
|store|prod|
+-----+----+
|51   |42  |
|51   |42  |
|89   |44  |
+-----+----+


scala>
```

Comment: @touelv.. does parsing like this help?.

Comment: It does and I appreciate that idea. The answer directly above and directly below this post also works, in a simplified fashion

Comment: DownVoters.. what is wrong with the solution?..please mention it in comments before you do..  it works for the OP..